# unsure why pyspark is treating my list as string

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `df` below:

```
| year | id  | area | visitor
| 2007 | 001 | GFD  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':20}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':4}]
| 2009 | 045 | TGH  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':20}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':5}]
| 2009 | 019 | GFD  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':14}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':55}]
| 2007 | 002 | GFD  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':15}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':35},{'id':'AA3' 'age':58}]
| 2007 | 003 | GFD  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':16}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':23}]
| 2007 | 006 | TGH  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':16}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':14},{'id':'AA3' 'age':60}]    
| 2007 | 008 | TGH  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':17}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':12}]
| 2008 | 010 | TGH  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':18}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':16},{'id':'AA3' 'age':23}]    
| 2007 | 044 | GFD  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':25}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':17},{'id':'AA3' 'age':52}]
| 2008 | 055 | TGH  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':25}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':43}]
| 2007 | 032 | TGH  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':22}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':77}]
| 2007 | 034 | TGH  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':34}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':10},{'id':'AA3' 'age':51}]
| 2009 | 077 | GFD  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':34}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':10},{'id':'AA3' 'age':12}]
| 2007 | 025 | GFD  | [{'id':'AA1' 'age':34}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':10}]
```

I am trying to use pyspark to group the data together by `area` and then find out the average age for the visitors in that area, and the most common visitor age for that area.

so initially, i used `groupBy` to put them together:

```
df.groupBy("area").agg(collect_list("visitor").alias("visitor_flatten"))

+-----------+---------------------+
|     area  |      visitor_flatten|
+-----------+---------------------+
|     GFD   |  [[{id=AA1, age=2...|
|     TGH   |  [[{id=AA1, age=2...|
```

But when I try to do a `.withColumn("test", explode("visitor_flatten"))` I get an expanded list of areas with 1 visitor entry per row (eg: {'id': 'AA1', 'age'=22}), but that data is being treated as a string. so I can't seem to use a `udf` or any `api` functions to extract the age out of it and do stuffs with the data. like find the average age of visitors in that area.. as well as how to find the most common visitor age within that area.

any thoughts / helpwill be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the avg age grouped by area. This should work for you with slight modifications.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

pdf = pd.DataFrame([["2007", "001", "GFD", "{'id':'AA1' 'age':20}, {'id':'AA2' 'age':24},{'id':'AA3' 'age':4}"]]\
                   , columns=['year', 'id', 'area', 'visitor'])

keys = ["id", "age"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)\
.withColumn("visitor", F.explode(F.split(F.col("visitor"), ",")))\
.withColumn("visitor", F.trim(F.col("visitor")))\
.withColumn("visitor", F.regexp_replace(F.col("visitor"), r"[{}']", ""))\
.withColumn("visitor", F.expr("str_to_map(visitor, ' ', ':')"))\
.select("*", *[ F.col("visitor")[k].alias(k) for k in keys ])\
.groupBy("area")\
.agg(F.avg("age").alias("avg_age"))

df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregation code looks just fine and it should do the job, unless your original data has some issues (i.e the data come as a string instead of JSON format). This is my test code with your data above, and I set up a proper schema:

```py
raw = [
    {'year':2007, 'id': '001', 'area': 'GFD', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':20}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':4}]},
    {'year':2009, 'id': '045', 'area': 'TGH', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':20}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':5}]},
    {'year':2009, 'id': '019', 'area': 'GFD', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':14}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':55}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '002', 'area': 'GFD', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':15}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':35},{'id':'AA3', 'age':58}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '003', 'area': 'GFD', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':16}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':23}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '006', 'area': 'TGH', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':16}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':14},{'id':'AA3', 'age':60}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '008', 'area': 'TGH', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':17}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':12}]},
    {'year':2008, 'id': '010', 'area': 'TGH', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':18}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':16},{'id':'AA3', 'age':23}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '044', 'area': 'GFD', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':25}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':17},{'id':'AA3', 'age':52}]},
    {'year':2008, 'id': '055', 'area': 'TGH', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':25}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':43}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '032', 'area': 'TGH', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':22}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':77}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '034', 'area': 'TGH', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':34}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':10},{'id':'AA3', 'age':51}]},
    {'year':2009, 'id': '077', 'area': 'GFD', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':34}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':10},{'id':'AA3', 'age':12}]},
    {'year':2007, 'id': '025', 'area': 'GFD', 'visitor': [{'id':'AA1', 'age':34}, {'id':'AA2', 'age':24},{'id':'AA3', 'age':10}]},
]

df = (spark
    .createDataFrame(raw)
    .select('year', 'id', 'area', 'visitor')
)

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- year: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- area: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- visitor: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- key: string
#  |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

agg = df.groupBy("area").agg(F.collect_list("visitor").alias("visitor_flatten"))

agg.show(10, False)
# +----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |area|visitor_flatten                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
# +----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |GFD |[[{age -> 20, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 4, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 14, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 55, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 15, id -> AA1}, {age -> 35, id -> AA2}, {age -> 58, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 16, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 23, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 25, id -> AA1}, {age -> 17, id -> AA2}, {age -> 52, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 34, id -> AA1}, {age -> 10, id -> AA2}, {age -> 12, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 34, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 10, id -> AA3}]]|
# |TGH |[[{age -> 20, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 5, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 16, id -> AA1}, {age -> 14, id -> AA2}, {age -> 60, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 17, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 12, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 18, id -> AA1}, {age -> 16, id -> AA2}, {age -> 23, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 25, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 43, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 22, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 77, id -> AA3}], [{age -> 34, id -> AA1}, {age -> 10, id -> AA2}, {age -> 51, id -> AA3}]]|
# +----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

agg.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- area: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- visitor_flatten: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- key: string
#  |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

agg.withColumn("test", F.explode("visitor_flatten")).select('test').show(10, False)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |test                                                                    |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{age -> 20, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 4, id -> AA3}] |
# |[{age -> 14, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 55, id -> AA3}]|
# |[{age -> 15, id -> AA1}, {age -> 35, id -> AA2}, {age -> 58, id -> AA3}]|
# |[{age -> 16, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 23, id -> AA3}]|
# |[{age -> 25, id -> AA1}, {age -> 17, id -> AA2}, {age -> 52, id -> AA3}]|
# |[{age -> 34, id -> AA1}, {age -> 10, id -> AA2}, {age -> 12, id -> AA3}]|
# |[{age -> 34, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 10, id -> AA3}]|
# |[{age -> 20, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 5, id -> AA3}] |
# |[{age -> 16, id -> AA1}, {age -> 14, id -> AA2}, {age -> 60, id -> AA3}]|
# |[{age -> 17, id -> AA1}, {age -> 24, id -> AA2}, {age -> 12, id -> AA3}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# only showing top 10 rows

agg.withColumn("test", F.explode("visitor_flatten")).select('test').printSchema()
# root
#  |-- test: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- key: string
#  |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```